# Django 404 error when loading <img> tag inside template

Tags: python, django

I have ~26k pictures inside my static folder that I want to load using a template that I have in Django

```
{% for movie in movies %}
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card card--list">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="card__cover">
                                    <img src="{% static 'img/covers/{{ movie.movie_id }}.jpg' %}">
                                    <a href="/movie/{{ movie.movie_id }}" class="card__play">
                                        <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                                <div class="card__content">
                                    <h3 class="card__title"><a href="/movie/{{ movie.movie_id }}">{{ movie.movie_title}}</a></h3>
                                    <span class="card__category">

                                        <a href="#">Comedy</a>
                                        <a href="#">Adventure</a>

                                    </span>

                                    <div class="card__wrap">
                                        <span class="card__rate"><i class="icon ion-ios-star"></i>{{ movie.movie_rating }}</span>

                                        <ul class="card__list">
                                            <li>HD</li>
                                            <li>16+</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="card__description">
                                        <p>{{ movie.movie_overview }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

The line

```
<img src="{% static 'img/covers/{{ movie.movie_id }}.jpg' %}">
```

is where I am facing an issue, the console shows img/covers/&7B&Dmovie.movie_id&3B&D.jpg

Comment: Does photo shows when, you directly go to say __localhost/static/img/covers/movie_thumbnail__ ??

Comment: Can you try this: __<img src="/static /img/covers/{{ movie.movie_id }}.jpg">__ and let us know if it works??

Comment: It looks like either the file name you are passing is wrong, or the statics are not properly configured in your settings. Did you collect the statics upfront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move nested curly braces outside:

```
<img src="{% static 'img/covers/' %}{{ movie.movie_id }}.jpg">
```

`static` template tag only converts relative "static" url to "absolute" one, so appending some details like filename or query params like shown is fine.